# Need help identifying unnamed micro-controller

Tags: microcontroller, identification, reverse-engineering

The chip I want to identify is a micro-controller with RSA cryptography acceleration utilized in a USB module. I suspect it is a chip manufactured by Chinese manufacturer and it might not be a general purpose product as well.

This is the schematic I extracted from the board: [image]

And this is the board photo:
[image]

Comment: note that identifying the MCU usualy does no good without the firmware

Comment: Since I've contracted to write such software, all I can say is that you can't tell about the MCU alone. Some contractors are even using 8051 cores, for example (one I contracted wanted me to write machine code for an 8051 core.) So it's not easy to adduce from your information so far.

Comment: @DKNguyen, I know that. I am interested in the micro-controller alone. The firmware part can be done after that. I actually want to get my hands to a RSA-2048 accelerated micro-controller with minimal driving elements required, like this one. Any information or lead on such micro-controller will be of great help too. Thanks

Comment: @jonk, I'm testing my chance on people who have experience on this exact chip to visit my question here. I know that the provided information is not enough. But that is all I could get from the PCB board. Do you have any suggestion on any other information I can extract from what I have?